# Can the microphone on webcams, e.g. the Logitech C920S, work for recording audio even when you're not using the camera?

Tags: webcam, microphone, audio-recording, logitech-webcam

For example, if you want to use your webcam mic to simply record audio on your computer.

Comment: Most likely. But you'll be able to see this yourself: check the available audio inputs on your computer and there should be an audio input for the webcam's microphone.

Comment: Works fine with a 920 on a Mac; never tried it on Windows.